# Generating statistics from line and hex grid in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, hexagonal-grid

I have a process I use QGIS/mmqgis for.  I have a hex grid that I use for binning large data, and I have that hex grid overlaying a road network.  I use the "Join Attributes by Location (Summary)" tool to generate a new road network that has a series of statistics derived from all the cells a line traverses.  Maybe more helpful to see the principle:

[image: road statistics from hex grid]

QGIS will give me a new road network and each feature has a min, max, mean, sum, range, etc derived from all the hex cells that feature intersects.  In the example graphic, the processed top line would have a sum of 500 and the tributary line would have a sum of 495.

I have tried to reproduce this analysis in ArcGIS Pro for a series of users who only have Esri tools, and have not been able to do so.  I have tried using Summarize Within, and this "sort of" works, but it creates a duplicate of each feature (line) for each hex cell it traverses and thus gives me no statistics.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Pythonic solutions are fine as long as there is an explanation of which method to use in particular.

Comment: What precisely have you tried with ArcGIS Pro? Where precisely are you stuck?

Comment: Intersect and summarise using unique line id.

Comment: I have the polyline layer loaded, I have the hex bins that contain a 'count' field.  I have tried: Spatial Join, and have tried setting the point count field (from the hex cells) to "mean" to run an average; I've also tried using Summarize Within, but both of these approaches leave me with duplicate geometry with no summarized point count statistics.  So regarding the example i posted, Arc gives me 4 duplicate lines, each with an attribute of 150, 175, 150, and 25, respectively.

Comment: Use summary statistics tool on that and perhaps read my 1st comment again.

Comment: @FelixIP that worked, thanks!  If you want to flesh it out and put it as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input:

[image]

Workflow that will handle overlaps:

```
arcpy.Intersect_analysis("LINES #;POLYGONS #", "./intersect.shp")
arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management("intersect", "LINE_ID;PGON_ID")
arcpy.Statistics_analysis("intersect", "./intersect_Statistics", "W SUM", "LINE_ID")
```

Output:

[image]